# Selenium и клик по кнопке

Tags: xpath, selenium, java

Здравствуйте.
Есть такая кнопка:

```
<input type="submit" value="Начать переписку" accesskey="s" class="button primary" />
```

Пытаюсь нажать её так:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class=\"button primary\"][0]")).click();
```

Не выходит.Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Используйте следующий код

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//input[@class='button primary']")).get(0).click
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри используя firebug находится ли твой элемент в пределах заданной страницы в коде css. Возможно при даже верном xpath тебе не удасться это сделать. Таким образом найдя видимый элеент кликай на него, можно пробовать js (JavascriptExecutor) или action (Actions) на крайняк.
Кстати твой xpath можно написать так:

```
//input[@value='Начать переписку']
//input[@type='submit']
//input[@accesskey='s']
//input[@class='button primary'] - наиболее подходит
```

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='button primary']")).click();
```